# MethodError: `convert` when using types defined in modules in separate files

Tags: types, julia

This question concerns using types, and vectors of types. I get `MethodError: convert` when I have two files, `Foo.jl` and `Baz.jl`, which contain one module each, and each module contains one type.

1. The contents of `Foo.jl`:

   ```
   module FooModule
   type Foo
     bar::Int
   end
   end
   ```
2. The contents of `Baz.jl`:

   ```
   module BazModule
   include("Foo.jl")
   type Baz
     qux::Vector{FooModule.Foo}
   end
   end
   ```

Type `Foo` contains an `Int`, and type `Baz` contains a `Vector` of `Foo`.

To get the error I open a Julia 0.4.7-pre+3 REPL where these files are stored and type

```
include("Foo.jl")
include("Baz.jl")
foo1 = FooModule.Foo(1)
baz1 = BazModule.Baz([foo1])
```

where the 4th command gives this error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{BazModule.FooModule.Foo}, ::FooModule.Foo)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor BazModule.FooModule.Foo(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  BazModule.FooModule.Foo(::Any)
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, ::T)
  ...
 in copy! at abstractarray.jl:310
 in call at /Users/james/Documents/code/julia/julia/Baz.jl:5
```

There seems to be an error due to the difference between the `FooModule` associated with the `include` statement in `BazModule`, and the `FooModule` in `Foo.jl` itself.

What is(are) the error(s) in my code, and how I should change my style to remove the error(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this change to your code and it worked for me

```
module BazModule
    using FooModule
    type Baz{T<:FooModule.Foo}
        qux::Vector{T}
    end
end
```

I think the problem with what you were doing was that you redifined the first module, the **Foo** module in the second line of the second document

```
include("Foo.jl")
```

If you look at the error you got you will notice

```
"call to the constructor BazModule.FooModule.Foo"
```

which should give you some idea of the error

tl;dr you should write "using X" instead of include(".jl that includes X")